# Finding Shortest Path between two coordinates points using pgrouting A-Star

Tags: pgrouting, gps, osm2po

In PostGIS I have two tables: an osm road network and a table that contains the start and end coordinate points of each path (i.e. userid, start_x1, start_y1, end_x2, end_y2).

I would like to know:

1. how to create an osm road network that can be used for implementing the Astart algorithm with pgrouting (I actually have an osm road network which I obtained using osm2po and that works fine Dijkstra shortest path algorithm using pgrouting layer plugin)?
2. how to find the shortest path of each start and end coordinate points using A-star?

Answer (score 1):

You can use, in a smart way, some of the postgis geometry relationship functions to find the nearest node to the given point coordinates, and then make use of the pgrouting functions (shortest_path, shortest_path_astar, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#a-star) chapter about A-Star?
It should answer your questions.